# Eclipse plugin development: unknown size of plugin during installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

I'm developing a plugin for Eclipse.

I'd like to see the actual size of my plugin displayed in the installation details window while installing it. Unfortunately a "Size: Unknown" is reported, even if I added the

```
   <plugin
     id="my.plugin.id"
     download-size="2000"
     install-size="2000"
     version="0.0.0"/>
```

fragment in my feature.xml file.

How can I force Eclipse to take care about the actual size of my plugin?

Thank you

cghersi